# How I can copy an object and then to compare prev and next?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I have such object:

```
const obj = {age: 20}
```

But value of `age` can be changed , for example, to `30`;
Then I need to compare previous object's values and new object's values. So how I can save first object before it will change it's structure.

```
const obj = {age: 20} //object what I have at the beggining
const newObj = obj; // {age: 30}
JSON.stringify(obj) === JSON.stringify(newObj) // false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should not mutate an obj, instead you can create a new copy using [... syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048953/what-do-these-three-dots-in-react-do):

```
const obj = {age: 20};
const newObj = {...obj};
```

Then do what you want to do with `newObj`

Comment: It works for me, only when I change object 1 time, but when i change 2 or more times it saves what it was before. For example, firstly age = 20, then i changed to 30, copy has value age which is = 20, but when i change 30 to 40, copy has value age which is = 30. Can I copy one time and save it?

Comment: you need to make a copy every time you edit it.