# How to replace single html element with multiple html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have a single HTML element that I want to be replaced in the body

i.e. this is the body

```html
<p> some random element </p>

<a href="#" id="dfd32"> some text</a>  //  this element to replace 

<h1> some random element </h1>
```

Now I want this element to get replaced by an array of elements

```js
[ 
  <a href="#" id="dsd32dsd"> 23dfsome text12</a>, 
  <a href="#" id="dfwedwew"> sdfsome text23</a>, 
  <a href="#" id="dssfd"> somdfse text2</a>
]
```

the final body after getting replaced will be

```html
<p> some random element </p>

<a href="#" id="dsd32dsd"> 23dfsome text12</a>
<a href="#" id="dfwedwew"> sdfsome text23</a>
<a href="#" id="dssfd"> somdfse text2</a>

<h1> some random element </h1>
```

How to do that ? I tried with `replaceWith` but not able to do it.

Comment: Surround the a tag with a div, then target this div and replace it with the contents of your array. Use join on your array to create one big string.

Comment: Please show the [`.replaceWith(...nodes)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceWith) approach because that would be one suitable solution

Comment: Since you've tagged the question with Jquery, and not with Javascript. Do you require a Jquery only solution?

Comment: @0stone0 No issue with javascript too. Jquery will be better.

Comment: _"it's not possible with replaceWith"_ - Then why did you accept the answer with `.replaceWith()`?

Comment: Although no one is required to explain a down vote, but... From the tooltip: _"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful (click again to undo)"_ - This question doesn't show any research effort, hence -> DV. @chaitanyagupta Care to explain what this has to do with reputation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234626/discussion-between-anuresh-verma-and-andreas).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't insert a NodeList directly, since [`replaceWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceWith) does not accepts an array as parameter.

Luckily there are some ways around this

---

### JavaScript

If we use the [spread operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048953/what-do-these-three-dots-in-react-do) (`...`) on our array with nodes, [`replaceWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceWith) will insert the elements as expected:

```js
// Array to replace
const ar = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    let tmp = document.createElement('a');
    tmp.innerHTML = 'Link #' + i;
    ar.push(tmp);
}

// Get element to replace
const el = document.getElementById('dfd32');

// Insert the array nodes
el.replaceWith(...ar);
```

```html
<p> some random element </p>
<a href="#" id="dfd32"> some text</a>
<h1> some random element </h1>
```

---

### jQuery

jQuerys version of [`replaceWith`](https://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) does work with a regular array containing DOM elements:

```js
// Array to replace
const ar = [ $('<a>Link #1</a>'), $('<a>Link #2</a>'), $('<a>Link #3</a>') ];

// Get and replace
$('#dfd32').replaceWith(ar);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p> some random element </p>
<div href="#" id="dfd32"> some text</div>
<h1> some random element </h1>
```

Comment: Can you provide your previous code with an alternate solution? That was better in my case I think.

Comment: Okay, no issues :)

Comment: _"There isn't a Jquery Solution thats cleaner than this"_ - Erm... [`$.replaceWith()`](https://api.jquery.com/replaceWith) -> `$("#dfd32").replaceWith(arr)`

Comment: Mmm, no clue why that didn't work. Added it to my answer.