# reactjs ES6: Unable to understand the syntax

Tags: reactjs

I am going through reactj hook forms and I find this syntax

```
<input {...register("firstName")} />
```

But how to understand this

I generally can understand the below syntax

```
<input myProp={something} />
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax
It can also resolve objects, `register` will probably return it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the three dots notation do in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048953/what-does-the-three-dots-notation-do-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) is a way to expand an object or an array inline.

I'm assuming you're using react-hook-form (though I could be wrong!) - in that case, the [register function](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register/) returns an object that looks like { onChange, onBlur, name, ref }. Therefore, this

```
<input {...register("firstName")} />
```

is the same as

```
const { onChange, onBlur, name, ref } = register("firstName");
// the above, in case you're also unfamiliar with destructuring, would be the same as
// const registerResult = register("firstName");
// const onChange = registerResult.onChange;
// etc.
<input onChange={onChange} onBlur={onBlur} name={name} ref={ref} />
```

Comment: Thank for the more breakup