# what is difference between prevUsers = [...users] & prevUsers = users javascript?

Tags: javascript, spread

i use this code snippet to make a copy of my user array :

```
var prevUsers = [...users];
```

but using "var prevUsers = users;" not working as well, and i want to know what is difference between these syntaxes ??

i checked prevUsers = [...users] & prevUsers = users with console.log but they return same results!
i want to know why prevUsers = [...users] works but prevUsers = users not works ...

thanks to everyone

Comment: depends if `users` is an actual Array, or something that is "Array-like", or just an *iterable* .... `var prevUsers = [...users];` is a bit like `var prevUsers = Array.from(users);` except it's not  the same, to be clear - it's a new Array for a start, not a reference to an existing array

Comment: There are dozens and dozens of exemples explaining these kind of stuff https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048953/what-does-the-three-dots-notation-do-in-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the three dots notation do in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048953/what-does-the-three-dots-notation-do-in-javascript)

Comment: @AminZekri I think you can find your answer below. Best of luck :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your question consists of two sub questions:

1. why "var prevUsers = users;" doesn't work
2. what is the difference between "var prevUsers = users;" and "var prevUsers = [...users];"

I would need a little more detail (e.g., full code) to answer the first, but I can provide one for the second.

See the code below:

```js
// creating array users
let users = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

// assigning users to prevUsers
var prevUsers = users;
console.log(prevUsers);

// modifying (deleting first element of) users
users.splice(0, 1);
console.log(prevUsers);
console.log(users);
```

You can see that assigning users to prevUsers is actually not a good practice because it is assigning the reference to the location of the users array, not creating a new array with identical content. Here's where the spread operator (...) comes in to play:

```js
// creating array users
let users = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

// creates new array with the content from users and assigns to prevUsers
var prevUsers = [...users];

// modifying (deleting first element) users
users.splice(0, 1);
console.log(prevUsers);
console.log(users);
```

Using the spread operator, you can create a new array, place the elements of users inside it, and then assign the new array to prevUsers. Since the two arrays are different arrays, "users.splice(0, 1);" will not affect elements inside prevUsers.

Comment: @AminZekri no prob! happy coding :)