# react-hook-form provides a syntax that I've never seen before, I would like to know the name of that

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I would like to know what syntax this is:

```
<input {...register("name")} />
```

Comment: Better to rephrase this question as I want to understand what's happening when this `register` function usage is being destructured on the input field. If your question was what's that `{...}` operator then that's spread operator + destructuring. They are general JavaScript concepts and not exclusive to react.

Comment: (Edited it for you but) Please provide code as text instead of image, so it can be searched or copied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the useForm documentation: https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register/

```js
const { onChange, onBlur, name, ref } = register('firstName'); 
// include type check against field path with the name you have supplied.
        
<input 
  onChange={onChange} // assign onChange event 
  onBlur={onBlur} // assign onBlur event
  name={name} // assign name prop
  ref={ref} // assign ref prop
/>
// same as above
<input {...register('firstName')} />
```

This is called object **destructuring**. You can learn more about it here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

### Explanation

The input element has many properties, like onChange, onBlur, name, ref... etc.

And the ***register*** function, when called by passing an argument, returns all of these properties that I've mentioned above.

So, this:

```
const { onChange, onBlur, name, ref } = register('firstName');
```

Creates four variables (const) that can be used later in my  element

```
<input 
   onChange={onChange}
   onBlur={onBlur}
   name={name}
   ref={ref}
/>
```

Now, let's say that I had a function that printed all of the values that register('firstName') had.

```
const printFunction = (onChangeParameter, onBlurParameter, nameParameter, refParameter) => {
    console.log(onChangeParameter, onBlurParameter, nameParameter, refParameter)
};
```

But I don't want to call it extracting each variable at a time and then putting it in the function (like this):

```
const { onChange, onBlur, name, ref } = register('firstName');
printFunction(onChange, onBlur, name, ref);
```

So I can just ***DESTRUCTURE*** register('firstname') inside the function.

```
printFunction(...register('register'));
```

And essentially get the same result, but much quicker.

This is what is happening in the input element. You're calling a function that returns multiple things, and grabbing each of those things and putting it into the input element.

Answer (score 0):

The `register` method helps you register an input field into React Hook Form so that it is available for the validation, and its value can be tracked for changes.

To register the input, we’ll pass the register method into the input field as such:

```
<input type="text" name="firstName" {...register('firstName')} />
```

https://blog.logrocket.com/react-hook-form-complete-guide/

Answer (score 0):

That `register('fieldName')`function returns all the props that can be passed to your field element. So in case of input, it is returning `name`, `value`, `onChange`/`onBlur`/`onFocus` and more (depends on how you configure them based on `mode` given to `useForm`).

If you want to see these before passing to your `input` field, you can do so.

```js
const fieldProps = register('firstName');
console.log(fieldProps);
<input {...fieldProps}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

`react-hook-form`  provides a register method which returns an object with fields onChange, onBlur, name, and ref.
You can see register method type is described as

```
register: (name: string, RegisterOptions?) => ({ onChange, onBlur, name, ref })
```

In order to connect your input control to `react-hook-form` you have two options. Either you use shorthand method

```
<input {...register('firstName')} />
```

Internally what it will do is this:

```
<input 
  onChange={onChange} 
  onBlur={onBlur} 
  name={name}
  ref={ref}
/>
```

Or you can manually take the return value from `register` method and add it to your input control like below:

```
const { onChange, onBlur, name, ref } = register('firstName'); 
        
<input 
  onChange={onChange} // assign onChange event 
  onBlur={onBlur} // assign onBlur event
  name={name} // assign name prop
  ref={ref} // assign ref prop
/>
```

`...` are called spread attributes which, as the name represents, it allows an expression to be expanded.
You can learn more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048953/what-are-these-three-dots-in-react-doing)