What is the significance of the spread operator in this code?
I am a React newbie. Please help me understand why a spread operator is used in the following. I've tried to run the same code without using it and I get all sorts of errors.
App.js contains:
import { useFormInput } from './useFormInput.js';

export default function Form() {
  const firstNameProps = useFormInput('Mary');
  const lastNameProps = useFormInput('Poppins');

  return (
    <>
      <label>
        First name:
        <input {...firstNameProps} />
      </label>
      <label>
        Last name:
        <input {...lastNameProps} />
      </label>
      <p><b>Good morning, {firstNameProps.value} {lastNameProps.value}.</b></p>
    </>
  );
}

The referenced file contains:
import { useState } from 'react';

export function useFormInput(initialValue) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);

  function handleChange(e) {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  }

  const inputProps = {
    value: value,
    onChange: handleChange
  };

  return inputProps;
}

From the little I understand, the spread operator copies/uses slices of arrays. But, I don't follow how that applies here.

@InSync: I see your point. However, when I search for "spread operator", that page you linked doesn't show up on the first page. Perhaps calling it a "spread operator" will make it easier for someone with a similar problem in the future, than "three dots". What do you think?

It's not an operator, it's simply Javascript syntax. There is no "spread operator", it's called Spread Syntax.

@DrewReese: w3schools call it an operator(https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_es6_spread.asp). It's probably wrong to do so, but I'm sure many JS newbies will continue to get confused. Would you agree?

I dunno, it's been around long enough it should no longer be confusing IMHO. ‍♂️ It's odd, you'd think an organization like W3 would get their information correct though.

@DrewReese: Perhaps there is a business opportunity there. It's quite likely that newbies will be directed to that page by Google and will continue to think so for a long time. Please search "spread operator" on this page to see other people with the same impression: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048953/what-are-these-three-dots-in-react-doing

That post is almost 10 years old... obviously there was confusion when the feature was introduced and people didn't bother to read any release documentation. I guess the use of "operator" is there to catch the stragglers. FWIW I too also called it an operator at one point.

"w3schools call it an operator" OK, that means W3Schools is wrong. Which shouldn't come as a surprise - it's a notoriously unreliable source Is it spread "syntax" or the spread "operator"?

The spread syntax works with more than just arrays. From MDN's spread syntax documentation: Spread syntax can be used when all elements from an object or array need to be included in a new array or object, or should be applied one-by-one in a function call's arguments list
In the case of your code, useFormInput returns an object with the keys value and onChange. Your code takes the resulting object and spreads it into an input element. Input elements can be provided an onChange and value (among other things), and the spread syntax is used here todo exactly that. The object property name is used when including the elements (properties) from the object in the input element, meaning that inputProps.onChange will be assigned to the input's onChange and inputProps.value will be assigned to the input's value.
// Typescript definitions to simplify
// const firstNameProps = { value: string, onChange: (e) => void}
// These statements do the same thing
<input {...firstNameProps} />
<input value={firstNameProps.value} onChange={firstNameProps.onChange} />

Removing the spread syntax will try to feed your object directly to the input element, which doesn't do it much good and will cause it to throw errors.
